# Static Files or Images doesn't load ( 404 ) using C# NET AngularJS project

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm new into AngularJS project in .NET 6.0 or Core. I just put a images into a folder like `wwwroot/imgs`

Then images are called from a custom static css referenced in: `angular.json` like:

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/css/main.css"
        ],
```

and then in main.css for example:

```
body {
  background: #fff9ee;
  background: url(/imgs/bg11.webp) repeat;
}
```

but the resource `https://localhost:port/imgs/bg11.webp` returns `404`
The css loads fine.

Also I'm using

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

in `Program.cs`

Also I check the `"Copy Always"` and `"Build Action: Content"`

**UPDATE:**

Problem also in `index.html` with a `GIF` file:

```
 <img class="img-fluid" src="/imgs/1.gif" alt="">
```

Tried with:

```
.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
})
```

neither works.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: If you type the same url directly in the browser, does the image load? Does a .gif file in the same location load?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing no, it redirects to the index page

Comment: @HansKeﬆing gif also return 404 but I discover that also doesn't work even in html in a src attribute in a img tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discover the problem. In development the project works through a reverse proxy, so we need to configure every folder in the file `proxy.conf.js` in order to the proxy let the project serve the static files.

For example, to add `/imgs` files in my case:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/imgs"
   ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the path of your css file **main.css**, if it is under **wwwroot** folder then just remove the **/** before imgs/bg11.webp.

Your css should look like this

```
body {
  background: #fff9ee;
  background: url('imgs/bg11.webp') repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't solve the problem.